# Элементарный пример лямбда выражения

Tags: java, lambda

В книге Шилдта приводится элементарный пример использования лямбда-выражения, 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
где метод

```
double myMeth(){ return 98.6; }
```

заменяется

```
() -> 98.6;
```

Я так понимаю, что приводимый выше пример метода является частной реализацией, некого функционального интерфейса.
Я попытался запустить этот пример, но почему-то у меня данное значение не возвращается как `double`, а выводится ссылка на объект экземпляра моего интерфейса. Что я делаю не так?

```
public interface FuncInterface {
    double myMeth (); 
}
```

и

```
public class Main {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FuncInterface n = () -> 98.6;
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
first.pack.Main$$Lambda$1/1418481495@87aac27
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем случае можно было просто воспользоваться `Supplier`:

```
Supplier<Double> n = () -> 98.6;
System.out.println(n.get());
```

`Supplier` - это тип функционального интерфейса, который предоставляет результат заданного типа, но при этом не принимает аргументов - в точности то, что нужно для Вашей функции `double myMeth(){ return 98.6; }` .

И Вы также можете заглянуть в исходник этого интерфейса - аналог того, как должен выглядеть Ваш `FuncInterface`, если Вы хотите реализовать его сами:

```
package java.util.function;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Supplier<T> {
    T get();
}
```

и, соответственно, результат получается аналогично `n.get()` (для `Supplier`) - `n.myMeth()` (для `FuncInterface`).

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
    System.out.println(n.myMeth());
```